# Websphere Application Server V8.5 Liberty Profile & accessing iSeries

Tags: web-services, deployment, ibm-midrange, egl, websphere-liberty

I'm trying to deploy our EGL-based webservice project on Websphere Application Server Liberty Profile V8.5.
The webservices are calling EGL-Generated cobol programs that are located on another server.
Also, we need a JDBC connection to the database located on the iSeries (Power7)
I have added this coding in server.xml:

```
  <dataSource id="db2iToolbox" jndiName="jdbc/db2iToolbox">
    <jdbcDriver libraryRef="DB2iToolboxLib"/>
        <properties.db2.i.toolbox databaseName="databaseforEGL" serverName="iseriesserver"/>
    </dataSource>

    <library id="DB2iToolboxLib">
        <fileset dir="C:\jars" includes="jt400.jar"/>
    </library>
```

This is the error thrown when the call-statement gets executed:

```
EGL0010E An external dependency is missing. The following exception occurred.
Exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
com.ibm.as400.access.ErrorCompletingRequestException
EGL0002I The error occurred in LoginLib processing the login function.
```

I'm assuming the jt400.jar doesn't get loaded.
Also tried the default fileset dir:

```
 <fileset dir="/QIBM/ProdData/Http/Public/jt400/lib" />
```

source: 
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.doc/ae/twlp_dep_configuring_ds.html

Comment: To eliminate a possibility, review [Trying to call an RPG program](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014505313) , specifically the reply from _dan_darnell_ . Ensuring the suggested steps are taken might uncover an underlying issue.

Comment: Can you show the full stack trace of the NoClassDefFoundError? Is the application trying to also access the classes in jt400.jar? If so, the application needs to have a `<classloader commonLibraryRef="DB2iToolbackLib"/>`.

Comment: bkail, added the line u requested. error persists.
http://pastebin.com/TQz5xa3n

Comment: It looks like your application (or some library it uses) is printing the exception toString rather than printStackTrace. Can you fix that to show the full stack trace? Can you include your full server.xml here?

Comment: @bkail,  
  
I'm using Rational Business Developer (IBM's eclipse extension). The liberty profile is imported in the servers view. This probably is blocking the printStackTrace.  
  
I have started the server manually and this is the output: 
  
console.log : [link](http://pastebin.com/YDBEwDQc)  

messages.log : [link](http://pastebin.com/K2W7L71G)  
  
server.xml : [link](http://pastebin.com/3ZYHzFu9)  
  
(I noticed you typed 'DB2iToolbackLib', i tried that but tought you might ment 'DB2iToolboxLib' so the uploaded version contains the 2nd)

Comment: @bkail, I have followed your lead on the classloader & found my error.  
I had to define the classloader within the application tag, just as u suggested.  
This problem is resolved now. Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: Glad you got it working. Sorry I wasn't more explicit.

Comment: @bkail or Niek could you type your solution as answer, so the question can be marked as answered ;-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The application needs to be configured to use a common library reference so it has visibility to the same class:

```
<application ...>
    <classloader commonLibraryRef="DB2iToolbackLib"/>
</application>
```